# Activating script with a button in the same form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've got a form, with just normal `<input type="text">` its already in a form. But what I want to do, is having a randompassword generator to generate a password for the password field. The button needs to activate a script and put the value into the password field.

but its not possible to submit a form in a form right?

example code:

```
<?php
//password gen
if (isset($_POST['passgen'])) {
  $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
  $generated_password = substr(str_shuffle($charset), 0, 12);   
}
//password gen end
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit-form-with-text" value="submit form"/> 
<input type="submit" name="activate-the-passgen" value="Generate a password"/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $generated_password; } ?>" size="15" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: use ajax for this purpose

Comment: My guess it that approximately zero users will use the option to generate a password, as they won't remember it and will choose to use a password they remember instead.

Comment: nested form is not possible but multiple forms is, store the generated pwd in the session and use it in the last submit, Ajax is a good option too

Comment: How do i call such option with ajax so i cna look it up?

Comment: @PhpRookie: I posted answer with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use jquery then try it:
**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/7/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#genPass").click(function(){
        chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var result = '';
        for (var i = 15; i > 0; --i)
            result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
         $("#pass").val(result);
    })   
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" name="submit-form-with-text" value="submit form"/>
    <input type="button" id="genPass" name="activate-the-passgen" value="Generate a password"/>
    <input type="text" value="" id="pass" size="15" />
</form>
```